# ReactJS server cache with Redis not working

Tags: reactjs, caching, redis

I have a React website that needs a lot of data from the api but, after getting it, all the users would see the same data. I am trying to use Redis for cache but I don't know if it is possible to connect react directly to Redis in the same vm it is hosted.

I tried using the redis for node.js but it didn't work, I get this error

"Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at node_modules/redis-errors/index.js"

Redis is runnign on the server

this is the code I'm using

```
import { createClient } from "redis";

const redisClient = createClient()

redisClient.on('error', err => console.log('Redis client error', err))

await redisClient.connect()

export default redisClient
```

```
 await redisClient.set('key', props)
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do? Or m I doing something wrong here?